# Email password fails with & in it

Tags: email, password, smtp

Wondering if anyone has seen this before, where on Exim 4.85 an email password fails because it had an & in it?

As you can imagine it took ages to get to the bottom of what was going on. Kept resetting customer's password, it kept failing.

Then I had an idea and put a pretty simple password and it succeeded. So went back to the original password which was something like Jumpy05#&* and working with the customer logging into webmail, started building the password

```
Jumpy05 - worked
Jumpy05# - worked
Jumpy05#& - failed!
```

Aha!!! Talk about obscure.

But the important question is why? Anyone seen this before? Is there a setting somewhere to override this?

I suspect it has something to do with & being part of querystrings, but am not sure. Ideas or solutions welcome.

Comment: Can you give us the name and version of the email server/application ?

Comment: Mailserver is Exim 4.85

Comment: ok, and what interface is the password being typed into ? Possible examples would be "bash prompt", "cPanel", "custom written php web interface", some java app etc etc etc.

Comment: @JohnMcNamara it was happening with cpanel webmail and also her mac mail client.  So it seems to have been a general issue, not a client issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: understood. What password store is Exim using ? That's probably most relevant. I found refs to the ampersand being special in user names at the following but nothing about passwords ...  http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html    ......   http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html

Comment: I am not sure how to find that.  But I just had a thought.  I wonder if rather than just the & it is the combination  !& that is the issue.  Maybe the bang has some significance in this context.  Might have to do some testing.  Oh. I had faked the password, the original actually had !&# as the trailing symbols.  Sigh...

Comment: I would think that any connection with query strings or hash bangs is coincidental? I would have thought the most probable cause was an encoding issue, either when the password is first set/stored or at the time of authentication - since it seems to affect multiple clients then when/how the password is initially set.

Comment: Well I have now done some tests on a couple of mail accounts and can't recreate it.  However it was most certainly happening the other day.  Perhaps it is an encoding thing, who knows.  I think the mystery will never be solved.  But at least I might now get the tumbleweed badge :o)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with most scripting and/or framework because the ampersand (&) references a variable in the source code. Similar unsupported characters may also include brackets ( [ ] ) or angle brackets ( < > ).